# Applescript Application will Add Key/Value Pair to Multiple Applications

Tags: applescript

My goal was to create a drag'n'drop AppleScript application that will replace NSUIElement key/value pairs in the application's info.plist file. This will effectively hide application's icons from the Dock & Application-Switcher.

So far this creates an extra 'Info.plist' file called "Info.plist.plist" in ƒContents, with the NSUIElement value as the only key/value pair (it will not ammend the original file). Can you suggest a solution?

```
-- OS X 10.3.9
on open ItemList
    repeat with x in ItemList
        set apppath to POSIX path of x
        set infile to quoted form of (apppath & "Contents/Info.plist")
        do shell script "defaults write " & infile & " 'NSUIElement' '1'"
    end repeat
end open
```

Comment: Why do you mention `-- OS X 10.3.9`? Does it work on 10.3.9 or doesn't it or is the script meant to run on 10.3.9?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I have enough info to come up with an answer, but my guess is that

```
do shell script "defaults write " & infile & " 'NSUIElement' '1'" with administrator privileges
```

will work.